# Dependency injection by type names

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dependency-injection, autofac

For my example I use Autofac (it's not necessary):

```
var r = builder.RegisterType<Helper>().As<IHelper>(); // usual using
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to register types somehow like:

```
string name1 = "Helper";

string name2 = "IHelper";

var r = builder.RegisterType<GetTypeFromName(name1)>().As<GetTypeFromName(name2)>();
```

Is it possible to do with reflection magic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a mechanism that would "figure out" which concrete types you want to register and how to expose them (the `As` part in AutoFac). Here is a sample of how you can register using `System.Type` so the missing part is obtaining the `System.Type`s yourself.

```
// get your Type(s)
Type concreteType = typeof(Helper);
Type asType = typeof(IHelper);

// Autofac registration call
builder.RegisterType(concreteType).As(asType);
```

As you can see in the above code you should call the non-generic version of the `RegisterType` and `As` methods. (The generic versions really just call down to these anyways).

Comment: Hey, I even didn't think about non-generic version! Yes, I'm able to get both types, but unfortunately after resolving I get ComponentNotRegisteredException for 'asType' (IHelper). Any ideas?

Comment: @amplifier - Does type `Helper` implement interface `IHelper`?

Comment: Yes, it does. Checked it, otherwise my "static" resolver wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Generally to resolve a type name you would need to provide more information than just the class name.  So I guess the answer is "not exactly".

The method for mapping a string to a type is `Type.GetType`, which is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2

As you can see, in a vacuum we can't say that `"Helper"` or `"IHelper"` would be sufficient.  You probably could get by with a namespace-qualified class name.  (The reason why `Helper` works in the "hard-coded" syntax, of course, is that the compiler can take advantage of `using` statements in deciding what `Helper` should mean.  That option doesn't work when `GetType` is trying to understand a string at runtime.)

If you can provide a custom resolver, maybe you can make it work exactly as you describe.

Comment: I can get type variable for Helper and IHelper this way: _Type typeArgument = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath).GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == className);_

Comment: Sure, and if that suits your use case, it's fine.  This means that you know what assembly the class comes from, which is a good place to start.  But also beware of that `First` method, which may not do what you want if the assembly should happen to contain two classes (in different namespaces) with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to get te `Type` object for the type you want to register, you can pass it to Autofac using a different overload of the `RegisterType` method, like so:

```
var type = Assembly.LoadFrom(path).GetType(typeName);
builder.RegisterType(type);
```

Comment: Great! But after resolving IHelper via __container.Resolve<IHelper>();_ I get ComponentNotRegisteredException for 'asType' (IHelper).

Comment: If concrete type and interface types are different, you still have to use the `As()` method as you did before.